# Balance does not match transactions

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerujo

I have some incoming transactions that does not seem to add correctly to the balance.

Blurry picture from Monerujo:

[image]

(Had to take a picture of the mirror and reverse it manually as screenshot is not possible here)

It should be somewhat clear that there are two big incoming transfers adding up to 210 and three big outgoing transfers adding up to around 108.
Still, the balance is only around 6. How is that possible?

The balance matches if the two incoming transfers are cut in half. That is, counts as 110 and not 210 as expected.
Same problem in official full node wallet - both cli and rpc.
All are synced and latest version.

What can be the cause? Bug or feature?

Comment: It's not like there is a running balance, and your screenshot doesn't show all your activity, so it's impossible to know what the deal with your balance is. If the balance doesn't agree with the activity, it could be the bug from v0.12.2.

Comment: It shows the latest activity, and as the balance can't be negative, wouldn't the balance have to be at least 210 - 108 = 102?
I still don't understand the bug. Is it the transaction or the balance that shows the wrong number and how can I fix it?
Assuming it is the transaction, the sender has knowingly abused the bug I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to the bug 4117: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4117

If so, then please ensure that you have the latest version of the app as it should have the fix that prevents that situation. If you are sure that you have the latest version, please update us here.

Comment: I was using "Windows, 64-bit Command-Line Tools Only" version 0.12.2.0 at the time. After upgrade to 0.12.3.0 the problem persists. And as the picture shows, Monerujo shows the same.
I don't understand the bug and it's consequences, so i'm not sure it's related.